# Java.IO.Filenotfoundexception error, Can't find a file that exists in C:

Tags: java, file, backslash

I am recently beginning programming and cannot get my program to find a file, then read input from it. Says the file does not exist. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class assignment3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("C:\\file\\Summary.txt");
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename;

        System.out.println("--------------------------------\nBowsers Nuclear Weapons Inventory\n" +
                "---------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the file: ");
        filename = k.next();
        File f = new File(filename);
        System.out.println(f);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);

        String Game1 = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Game1);

        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

At line Scanner inputfile = new Scanner(f);. The error mentioned appears.  Also when prompted to type in the file name in the program, i put "C:/Games.txt".....but when i got the filename to be printed out the filename is registerd as C:\Games.txt....why is the forward slash turning into a backslash. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: On Windows, `/` and `\ ` should be equivalent in file names, so this is nothing to worry about.  Many Windows programs accept `/` as a substitute for `\ ` because Linux users are more used to `/`, I guess.  Anyway, are you sure the file really exists in the top-level folder in `C:`?  Try bringing up a Command Prompt window and typing `dir C:\Games.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the forward slash turning into a backslash?

Because you're on Windows, and directories are natively separated by a `\`

Next, you don't appear to be writing with your `PrintWriter`. And if you want to check for a file that exists, call [`File#exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29).

```
File f = new File(filename);
if (f.exists()) {
  System.out.println(f);
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
  while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(inputFile.nextLine());
  }
} else {
  System.out.println(f.getPath() + " does not exist");
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but nothing comes up.....I'm assuming it thinks the file doesnt exist. But the Games.txt file is in my C drive.

Comment: @BrandonNolan Then the file does not exist, if it did the above would print it.

Comment: Thanks for your help....The file is actually named "Games.txt".....and is a txt file. So i had to type "Games.txt.txt"

I feel stupid

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the folder named "file" exists (for creating a file). It might throw that error if it's not there. For reading you need to have the proper rights.

Comment: I deleted that line and the error still comes up. I'm stumped haa

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Answer {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

        // Have to throw a FileNotFoundException just in case an error occurs the compiler needs to know how to process the error.

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("C:/file/Summary.txt");
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename;


        System.out
                .println("--------------------------------\nBowsers Nuclear Weapons Inventory\n"
                        + "---------------------------------");
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the file: ");
        filename = k.nextLine(); //Input for strings

        System.out.println(filename);
        File f = new File("C:/file/"+filename+".txt"); //Must have a location for your files
        f.createNewFile(); //The file's pathname is the only thing that you can supply when you instantiate the object
        //you actually have to invoke the createNewFile method upon the object.
        if(f.exists()) { //Don't be afraid to check your code this is a must for every programmer.
            System.out.println("Good! The File Exists");
        }

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);

        String Game1 = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Game1);

        inputFile.close();


    }
```

}

When you create a file you always have to throw a `FileNotFoundException` if you do not the compiler will not know what to do if the error occurs. Use / when specifying directories of files.

\ is generally used as an escape sequence and when you type this \ \ your basically telling it to escape itself this code is useful in other situations but not this one.

You can NOT create a new file by the initiation of the object you always have to invoke the createNewFile method upon the object so that you can create a new file. This is because no constructors automatically call the createNewFile method in the class. You might be wondering what the words in the parameter are, they just serve the purpose of naming the file directory. I have found a helpful link if you want to review creating Files. Just look under the constructors tab. [API Files Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

BE SURE! to always check your code, it does not matter how good of a programmer you are. You ALWAYS have to check for errors and if you make a game, and don't know where the error is among the millions of lines of code. You are going to have a hell of a time.

Lastly, I was not sure what you were trying to do after the if statement, but you will receive an error after the if statement, so if you want to ask me how to help with that just type in the comments of my post.